# website does't work in some network

Tags: dns

In the last month, my site no longer works on my computer or any computer connected to the same network that I use at home and I have tried other internet networks and the site doesn't work too, but strangely it works in some other networks!

The error message in the browser is : `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED`

I did not know the problem but when I looked at the site intoDNS I found 3 problems :

```
WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.
------
You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again: 

ns77.domaincontrol.com. 
ns78.domaincontrol.com. 
-------

ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
208.109.255.49 216.69.185.49
```

---

Also, two months ago I moved my domain from Godaddy to Namecheap.

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The domain's name servers are pointed to the servers of `Godaddy`, but there is no DNS zone for the domain there. You need to check what are the name servers of `Namecheap` (or another DNS hosting service) and point the name servers of the domain to these servers. Also you will have to create a DNS zone for the domain at the new DNS host (`Namecheap` or other of your choice) and create DNS records pointed to your web host's IP address.

If you only have a web site and no other services, like mail server you can only create two A records, like this:

```
Type: A
Host: @ (or empty, it means the same)
Target (or Value, or Points to): ip.of.web.site

Type: A
Host: www
Target: ip.of.web.site
```

Comment: I have changed the nameserver from CustomDNS to Basic Namecheap DNS, it that will fix the problem ?

Comment: I can't ckeck IP adress of my website  ( IP adress not found !) : https://ipinfo.info/html/ip_checker.php

Comment: Did you create the DNS zone of the domain and the DNS records at Namecheap? If not and you do not how you can contact Namecheap's support and ask them for instructions.